# Fast way to get and update disk space usage?

Tags: python, unix, diskspace

I need to monitor the network disk space usage and generate report listing directories and their sizes per user.
There are directories containing over 1000 files with each one 20mb big.
Speed is the key as the report needs to be updated frequently.

My Python script walks given directory and store each dir and file info into a dictionary of lists.
Post-process of the dictionary is swift. I/O is the bottleneck. With current script, a 35TB directory takes roughly 5-6 hours to scan.

I've tried the plain *os.walk* & *stat*, suprocessing *du*, *find -type f -printf*.

#### os.walk and du

They both drill down to the bottom and stat every dirs, files. While this is required for the initial run, subsequent updates take hits from unnecessarily stat'ing unmodified directories and files. And I can't set the max-depth since I need to know what's changed in subdirs, if anything's been changed.

#### find -type f

This will look for files only. Not much of difference from above. At least this doesn't stat directories (directory info are gathered from residing files). No noticeable improvement in speed.

I had hoped to use directory's *modified time* to check whether something's been changed inside. If so, dive in, else skip. But *mtime* only updates for created, deleted, renamed items in the directory.

So is there no other way than this brute-forcing through all the dirs and files?

```
Directory layout:
group_002/
    bob/
        fubar/
        etc/
    dave/
    jim/
```

Comment: What platform are you on?  Will a platform-specific solution be ok?

Comment: You can try the cross-platform [psutil](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/)

Comment: @SvenMarnach sure, i'm not looking for a silver bullet. On centos5.3

Comment: `find` has `-newer`, `-anewer`, `-cnewer`, and a few others.  None of these work?

Comment: @JBernardo i'll take a look at psutil

Comment: You say: "listing directories and their sizes per user"...do you basically have 1 directory/user (at some level) that you're trying to get sizes for, or are the user files/directories scattered/intermingled?

Comment: @Gerrat The top directory I specify contains a bunch of user dirs.

Comment: @Izkata I'm currently playing around with -mmin and -mtime. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @profitehlolz Actually, `-mtime` and its variants is what I was thinking of when I suggested that.  Not sure the versions of "newer" will be helpful

Comment: Have you heard of [quotas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_quota)? If you enable quota on a filesystem, it keeps track of every user's disk usage for you and a report is available instantly at any time with `repquota`.

Comment: @AlanCurry I'm not too familiar with quotas. Gonna have to talk to the sys admin but we don't want to put limits on the users.

Comment: I believe "find . -type f -print" will still stat directories as part of the hierarchy traversal.  It's been a while, but I believe quotas can be enabled without imposing limits on any users by giving them limits of 0.

Comment: You could enable quota to track usage and still leave eveyone's limit unset.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would be any faster, but you could try generating a list of user dirs, and then running them through [this recipe on disk usage](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577972-disk-usage/).